Removing data from blockchain
Does freeing or updating the storage map or any runtime storage in substrate deletes the old that in blockchain?
Does it done through pruning?

No.
It only impacts the most recent state.
You can still retrieve the previous historical state by specifying the optional at argument in the RPC.
For example:

